# Finding if there any element in the set has style.display !== "none";

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var isAnyBool = $(selector)
 .filter(function(){ return this.style.display !== "none"; })
 .length;

// if (isAnyBool) { .. }
```

This works as expected but needlessly counts all elements when all it's needed is simple true/false. How it could be improved to be more efficient?

**UPDATE:** since `visible` doesn't know if element is directly hidden, or some of the parents are actually hidden, I have to check `style.display` or something equal in functionality

Comment: `$('*').filter(':hidden').length`?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea check update section

Comment: some benchmarks, http://jsperf.com/test-display/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var isAnyBool =  $(selector+"[style*='display: none']").length > 0 ;
```

should be MUCH faster in modern browsers than iteration of any type.

since jQuery's :visible can be affected by more than just style.display, it's not the right tool for this job.

this checks the style attrib only, and does so without js iteration, making it the fastest and simplest solution offered at time of writing.

Comment: no need here to compare it to 0. What for not style setted inline?

Comment: 0 == false, all other result will be interpreted as true

Comment: More tangential semantics ;).  I also inferred the desire for a strict boolean.

Comment: `find` searches descendants. You would want `$(selector+'[style*="display: none"]').length`

Comment: What happens when there's no space between ":" and "none"?

Comment: @landons: hmm, never encountered, which browser does that?

Comment: @landons: it should be. i remember IE6 generating uppercase tags, but i don't recall how its style attributes looked... anyways, modern stuff seems to be consistent, but please let me know if you find otherwise.

Comment: I'll take this answer, here are some benchmarks, http://jsperf.com/test-display/3

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about performance efficiency, but this is far easier to read:

```
var isAnyBool = $(selector).is(':visible');
```

**Edit #2:**

I think [@dandavis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352254/finding-if-there-any-element-in-the-set-has-style-display-none/17352378?noredirect=1#answer-17352378) is the best one

Comment: I think if there is hidden parent element, then all children are invisible by your method, and I don't want this

Comment: @mpapec How's that not the case if you're manually checking `style.display`?

Comment: `style.display` tells if element is directly hidden by `.hide()` and visible sucks here

Comment: @mpapec Oh.. that's a nonobvious, nontrivial requirement ;)

Comment: Accodding to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/is/), `is` returns a boolean not an object with a `length` property

Answer (score 2):

You can make it simple with `:visible`

```
var isAnyBool = $(selector).filter(':visible').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of filtering and counting the elements, you can use the [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with the same callback:

```
var isAnyBool = $(selector).is(function(){ return this.style.display !== "none"; })
```

Comment: looks great, so `is()` isn't iterating over all elements?

Comment: @mpapec i'm quite sure it will

Comment: @mpapec Here is a jsperf for you http://jsperf.com/is-vs-filter but the results are different..

Comment: @mpapec: I had expected it to break once the first match was found, yes. But [actually it's not coded that clever](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L61)… :-( If you want that performance gain, you'll have to code it manually I fear

Comment: @roasted, Bergi tnx for benchmarks, I'll make some custom solution then

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't count.. `length` is a property not a function. So there is not much going on when you call `.length`

Instead of storing the length, I would store the result in case if it can be used elsewhere.

```
var mySelector = $(selector).filter(function(){ return this.style.display !== "none"; })

if (mySelector.length) { .. }
```

Comment: Of course building the arrayList and getting its length is *counting*?

Comment: this is the same method as OP's one.

Comment: @Bergi that `getting its length` part is not counting.. as it is already set when you filter.

Comment: @roasted The point in this answer is more about usability of length. There is nothing that needs to be done as he was asking for an alternative for `.length` or I am reading this question wrong.

Comment: @Vega I think the OP was looking for a more efficient way of getting to the result

Comment: @Vega: Yeah but during the `building the list` part the `length` gets incremented with every new matching element…

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure if this is more or less overhead, but seems more legible to me if you did it something like this:

```
$(selectSomeStuff).filter(!$(this).is(':visible'));
```

... or testable variable

```
var isAnyBool = $(selectSomeStuff).filter(!$(this).is(':visible')).length
```

... maybe as if statement

```
if ($(selectSomeStuff).filter(!$(this).is(':visible'))){
  var isAnyBool = true;
  // OR
  //.. do stuff here ...
}
```